# How do demo-versions know the test-time is over after re-installing?

Tags: windows, registration, uninstallation, demo, dvd

How do applications like CloneDVD2 or AnyDVD know that the free phase is over, even if the application was uninstalled and then re-installed? Those applications don't require the user to login so that they could identify the user again.

Also on deinstalling them a window pops up asking whether the "registration files" should be kept or not. Even if they are not kept, the re-installed application knows the demo-time is over.

How is that technically realized?

Comment: Typically a registry setting or file placed in an obscure location to make it harder to find.  Some software has even been known to store data in unused parts of the disk, typically between the master boot record and the first partition - this can cause trouble on dual-boot systems, because Linux uses that space.  (I'm kind of hoping that nobody does that any more, but I wouldn't bet on it!)

Comment: @Harry Johnston running everything inside a VM change that if I reset the VM every time?

Answer (score 1):

Could be everything...

You might reverse the algorithm to find out.

But to name an example:

It's possible to generate a hash, based on unique hardware identifiers, of your hardware configuration and send that over the internet to a database.

If your hash exists over there, the software knows you ran it before.

An other option is leaving tracking information inside of your OS. So the checkbox: delete register information, isn't deleting everything.

To test:

1) Switch GPU or CPU :P

2) Format & Reinstall computer

Comment: Interesting ideas, although I don't think I can change GPU and CPU that easily ;) But running it inside a VM might do that, couldn't it?

Comment: Just change your mac address in the VM, might be enough. If not try to changes unique id's of things. :P

Comment: I'll try that, thanks :) Is there a VM you'd recommand? It should be one in which you can manually edit such "uniquifying" values

Comment: VirtualBox is free, but I don't know how easy it is to change the unique values. Just give it a go :P Also try to make a snapshot of the beforestate, and look what differences occur after uninstallation, look what files were left behind.